# Adding multiple datasources to a datagridview vb.net

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` that I am importing data into from multiple excel files. But every time I import the data it overwrites the previous data. How do I get it to add the next excel file to the end of the previous in the data grid view?

```
If DataGridView1.RowCount > 0 Then
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Work\4pc_test1.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")

    'MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & fd.FileName & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)

    'DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)

    Dim tab As DataTable = DtSet.Tables(0)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = tab

    MyConnection.Close()
Else

    'The below connection allows for the opening of .xls files and .xlsx. The one reamed out below doesnt open up .xls files. 
    MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Work\4pc_test1.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")

    'MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & fd.FileName & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
    MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
    MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
    DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
    MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
    DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)

    MyConnection.Close()
End If
```

Comment: You cant have multiple DataSources for a DGV - its singular.  Is it me, or are both the If and Else blocks doing the same identical thing except one has an extra DataTable variable

Comment: Not for nothing, but you have asked 16 questions and gotten 18 answers; accepted only one and voted only once.  Accepting answers and upvoting posts you find useful helps others find good answers. The [Tour] explains it.  If the sources are identical, you can append to the data table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply fill a single `DataTable` multiple times and rows will be added to the `DataTable` this way. For example:

```
Try
    Dim table = New DataTable()
    Dim connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=D:\excel1.xlsx;" & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
    Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection)
        adapter.Fill(table)
    End Using
    connection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=D:\excel2.xlsx;" & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
    Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection)
        adapter.Fill(table)
    End Using
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = table
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString())
End Try
```

Number of columns in different excel files can be different, but if there is columns with the same name, the data of those columns should be of the same type.

Comment: I would urge that the SQL spell out the columns desired in order to be sure that `foo` will end up in the foo column with the other foos

Comment: @Reza Ahaei, Although your answer imports the data, it does not stack the new records at the end of the old records. For example, my first import is 100 records and my second is 200, I should then have 300 records in my data table.

Comment: @Chrisetiquette You will have 300 records.

Comment: Don't mix your questions with each other. This post is specific to the current question and imports 2 excel files successfully.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Should I make a separate post then?

Comment: A new post about what?

Comment: @RezaAghaei A post asking how to import multiple files into one data table. The example you gave me is not what I needed. I need to be able to browse many times with a file browser dialog and select multiple files to add to the data base. These files will have a variety and filenames. I just need the logic and then ill add the file browser dialog.

Comment: Above example shows you how to import 2 files into a `DataTable`. For example if the first file has 10 rows  and the second file has 20 rows, the `DataTable` will have 30 rows. The main point in answer is calling `adapter.Fill(table)`. Pay attention, the table should be in a scope which keep previous added rows. For example if you create a method which import rows from excel to a `DataTable` you should create `DataTable` at form level and pass it to that method and you should not create it in the method.

Comment: At least in order to the description which you have in the question and based on my tests, I believe it's exactly what you need and I can't understand which part of the answer may not be what you need or I don't have any idea about why you say *The example you gave me is not what I needed.* because in the example obviously I used 2 files *excel1.xlsx* and *excel2,xlsx* which could be simply chosen using open file dialog.

Comment: Any way, if you need to ask a new question, add a different question with enough description and add example input and desired output and add the code which you tried and say what's the problem. Feel free to notify me if you asked a new question and I'll try to help you to solve the problem :)